# How do I use sed to parse a string that includes hyphens?

Tags: linux, mac, terminal, sed

Input example:

`foobar_1-1     1024 x 1024`

Desired output

`foobar_1-1`

The hyphen is causing issues here. It's causing the output to be two items in the array:

`foobar_1, 1`

Any advice?

Comment: Please share your full SED command.

Answer (score 0):

sed by default doesn't do that, it's a problem in your sed command.

if you want to manipulate strings like your example you can also use awk:

```bsh
$ echo 'foobar_1-1     1024 x 1024' | awk -- '{ print $1 }'
foobar_1-1
```